# ¿Cómo borrar los elementos de un push?

Tags: array, angularjs, chart.js

Hice un combobox en angular en la que el usuario puede seleccionar cualquier mes y se filtran los datos de acuerdo al mes seleccionado. Ese procedimiento lo hace bien, mi problema es que los datos quedan alamcenados, es decir si selecciona abril y luego julio muestra los dos datos. ¿Cómo puedo eliminar los datos anteriores cuando el usuario seleccione otro mes?
Ya intente varias condiciones pero no funciona.

```js
 public  getFecha() {
   let m : number = 0;
   m = this.mes;
  for (let datos of this.ArrayDatos) {
      for (let dato of datos){
       var date = new Date(dato.fecha_hora_inicio);
       var mes = date.getMonth();
        if(m == mes){
         this.fecha.push(dato.fecha_hora_inicio);
        console.log(this.fecha);

        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es primero limpiar el array `this.fecha` simplemente igualandolo a una lista vacía `this.fecha = []`.

Quedaría algo así :

```
 public  getFecha() {
   let m : number = 0;
   m = this.mes;
   this.fecha = [] // limpiar la lista antes de los pushes
  for (let datos of this.ArrayDatos) {
      for (let dato of datos){
       var date = new Date(dato.fecha_hora_inicio);
       var mes = date.getMonth();
        if(m == mes){
         this.fecha.push(dato.fecha_hora_inicio);
        console.log(this.fecha);

        }
      }
    }

  }
```